# Apache 2.4 proxy add request parameter to all requets

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy, crafter-cms

I am using Crafter CMS with multi-tenancy. I am trying to setup Apache2.4 on RHEL7 to be a reverse proxy. http://site.example.com -> ajp://localhost:9009/?crafterSite=site

Here is my Apache2 virtual host configuration. I have ensured that mod_proxy and mod_rewrite are loaded. I can reach Crafter Delivery through the proxy but the rewrite isnt working as Crafter doesnt know what site I am trying to load. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.example.com
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
    RewriteEngine  On
    RewriteRule ^$ /?crafterSite=site [QSA,L]

    <Proxy *>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyPass               /       ajp://localhost:9009/
    ProxyPassReverse        /       ajp://localhost:9009/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the rewrite rule to be:

`RewriteRule (.*) $1?crafterSite=site [QSA,PT]`

Where `site` is your site ID.

The differences are:

- It rewrites anything coming in regardless of URL and preserves it (see the `(.*)` and `$1`)
- It's a passthrough `PT` (not a redirect). This means it augments the request with the param and lets it straight through to Crafter Engine.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, I'd been banging my head against this for too long.